# Oracle Spatial geometry transformation gives wrong output

Tags: oracle, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to convert SRID from 2180 to 2177. This is my sample code.

```
SELECT SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2002,2180,null,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(461273,290199996,608231,546195962,461280,489099996,608185,353195948)),2177) geometria FROM DUAL
```

The output is `MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(6374994,33906775,295683316,187577,6638854,92398028,551837709,962805,6387072,01129964,494707234,588496,6717195,04670803,358718858,239292)`
but when I use an online converter it looks like this(correct value):
`6527855.83,5911838.68  6527863.20 5911792.21`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is trivial, you used `,` instead of `.` when separating decimal parts. It happens to me sometimes too ;)

```
select sdo_cs.transform(
         mdsys.sdo_geometry(2002,2180,null,mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),
                            mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(461273.290199996,
                                                     608231.546195962,
                                                     461280.489099996,
                                                     608185.353195948)),
                            2177) geometria 
  from dual
```

Result:

```
6527855.83374364
5911838.68338696
6527863.68346768
5911792.56737736
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why someone separated each value with a comma in the code I'm working on instead of converting coordinates to decimal and put them in in array. The error was not visible because when debugging in VS2017, it displays commas instead of dots, even now when it's working fine.